# ReplayKit Broadcast Upload Extension with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, replaykit

I'm trying to implement `ReplayKit` screen broadcast in a SwiftUI app.

According to Apple i'll need a Broadcast Upload Extension to handle video upload, as well as few delegate methods to wrap the behaviour of choosing the right extension and starting the broadcast.

I have already set up the extension, but I'm having trouble connecting it to my simple SwiftUI app, which just broadcast the iPad screen, nothing else.

Let's imagine I have a simple SwiftUI app:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BroadcastView: View {
    
    @State private var broadcastStarted = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Button("Toggle") {
            startBroadcast()
        }
    }
    
    func startBroadcast() {
        if broadcastStarted {
            // Do something to start
        } else {
            // Terminate the broadcast
        }
        broadcastStarted.toggle()
    }
}
```

If I were to use Swift instead of SwiftUI, this would normally suffice:

```
import UIKit
import ReplayKit

class BroadcastViewController: UIViewController, RPBroadcastActivityViewControllerDelegate, RPBroadcastControllerDelegate {

    var broadcastController : RPBroadcastController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func startBroadcast(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.isSelected = false
            guard (self.broadcastController == nil) else {
                self.broadcastController?.finishBroadcast(handler: { (error) in
                    print(error as Any)
                })
                return
            }
        }else{
            RPBroadcastActivityViewController .load { (activity, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    activity?.delegate = self as RPBroadcastActivityViewControllerDelegate
                    self.present(activity!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - RPBroadcastActivityViewControllerDelegate
    func broadcastActivityViewController(_ broadcastAVC: RPBroadcastActivityViewController, didFinishWith broadcastController: RPBroadcastController?, error: Error?) {
        self.broadcastController = broadcastController
        self.broadcastController?.delegate = self
        broadcastAVC.dismiss(animated: true) {
            self.broadcastController?.startBroadcast(handler: { error in
                print("started broadcast \(error)")
            })
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - RPBroadcastControllerDelegate
    func broadcastController(_ broadcastController: RPBroadcastController, didFinishWithError error: Error?) {
        
    }

    func broadcastController(_ broadcastController: RPBroadcastController, didUpdateServiceInfo serviceInfo: [String : NSCoding & NSObjectProtocol]) {
        
    }
}
```

I guess I should be wrapping the controller in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in order to use it in my SwiftUI app, but I have no idea how. I have tried a few approches, but none of them worked. I also watched a few videos and read a few articles, but they all mostly explain how to show a picture picker or attach a delegate method to a text field.

Has any tried using ReplayKit broadcasting (not recording) together with SwiftUI to hand the broadcast over to Broadcast Upload Extension?
Any help wrapping the ViewController in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` is appreciated.

Comment: If you know how to do it (and actually did it) with UIKit why do you need SwiftUI?

Comment: @Asperi because I already have a functioning app written in SwiftUI and the only functionality that is missing = live broadcast. Rewriting the app in pure swift feels like a setback and is going to be my last resort if I don't find a viable solution in SwiftUI

Comment: SwiftUI offers a UiVIewControllerRepresentable; to piggyback on @Asperi, if this is done in UIKit, you could leave it there and bridge it without rewriting it.